# Get list of buffers from current neovim instance

Tags: lua

The function below is written in Lua and returns the list of buffers from the current neovim session, it also allows the option to specify a optional table (object) as a parameter, with a `listed` property to filter the type of buffer returned by the function (only listed buffers, or every single one).

```lua
local function get_buffers(options)
    local buffers = {}

    for buffer = 1, vim.fn.bufnr('$') do
        local is_listed = vim.fn.buflisted(buffer) == 1
        if options.listed and is_listed then
            table.insert(buffers, buffer)
        else
            table.insert(buffers, buffer)
        end
    end

    return buffers
end

return get_buffers
```

The `if`..`else` part seems a little bit off for me, I'm not sure if it can be improved, but something tells me that there's some way to make this less repetitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only case when you *don't* want a buffer included is when

- `options.listed` is *truthy* and
- `is_listed` is *falsy*

In **every other case** you want it included. If my understanding is correct you can simplify the `if` to a single branch:

```
 ...
    local is_listed = vim.fn.buflisted(buffer) == 1
    if not (options.listed and is_listed) then
        table.insert(buffers, buffer)
    end
 ...
```

That code is still calculating `is_listed` on every iteration. If you move it inside the conditional and [remove the parenthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), the code will be a bit more efficient (`is_listed` won't be calculated at all when `options.listed` is falsy)

```
 ...
    if not options.listed or vim.fn.buflisted(buffer) ~= 1 then
        table.insert(buffers, buffer)
    end
 ...
```

I think that is good enough. There's some extra perf changes chat can be done. `options.listed` and `vim.fn` could be localized into a local variable to make it slightly faster, too. And using `table.insert` is slower than direct table insertion. Final result:

```
local function get_buffers(options)
    local buffers = {}
    local len = 0
    local options_listed = options.listed
    local vim_fn = vim.fn
    local buflisted = vim_fn.buflisted

    for buffer = 1, vim_fn.bufnr('$') do
        if not options_listed or buflisted(buffer) ~= 1 then
            len = len + 1
            buffers[len] = buffer
        end
    end

    return buffers
end
```

There is an API question that is still worth mentioning. In most cases, [I try to avoid boolean parameters completely](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior). Instead, consider using two functions: `get_all_buffers()` (no params) to get all buffers, and `get_listed_buffers()` (no params) to get only the listed buffers.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your `if` and `else` branches is identical.

```lua
table.insert(buffers, buffer)
```

I prefer to use neovim api functions over similar vim functions (`bufnr`, `buflisted`).

[nvim_list_bufs()](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_list_bufs%28%29) gets the current list of buffer handles, and [nvim_buf_is_loaded()](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_buf_is_loaded%28%29) checks if a buffer is valid and loaded.

Here's an example that returns the buffers that are loaded.

```lua
function get_bufs_loaded()
    local bufs_loaded = {}

    for i, buf_hndl in ipairs(vim.api.nvim_list_bufs()) do
        if vim.api.nvim_buf_is_loaded(buf_hndl) then
            bufs_loaded[i] = buf_hndl
        end
    end

    return bufs_loaded
end
```

Comment: I'm not saying this is a bad answer, but you might want to read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). The more insightful observations you make about the code in the question the better your answer will be.